# Problem installing and running chatterbot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, chatterbot

I tried to install chatterbot with the following command

```
pip3 install chatterbot
```

It returns this error to me

```
Collecting chatterbot
Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pint>=0.8.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot) (0.17)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/bin/python /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-r5_c98e2/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-tfkavy5n/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (261 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
  Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
    Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
  Collecting Cython
    Using cached Cython-0.29.24-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.9 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
  Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
    Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (18 kB)
  Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
    Using cached thinc-7.0.8-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
  Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
    Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
  Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
    Using cached tqdm-4.61.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
  Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
    Using cached srsly-1.0.5-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (179 kB)
  Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
    Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
    Using cached numpy-1.21.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (17.0 MB)
  Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
    Using cached wasabi-0.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for preshed, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: numpy, cymem, wasabi, tqdm, srsly, preshed, plac, murmurhash, blis, wheel, thinc, setuptools, Cython
      Running setup.py install for preshed: started
      Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-install-3wuuouxg/preshed_dd0563dec5f54cb4a210a0676d307d73/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-install-3wuuouxg/preshed_dd0563dec5f54cb4a210a0676d307d73/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-record-0758mgue/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-tfkavy5n/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-tfkavy5n/overlay/include/site/python3.9/preshed
           cwd: /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-install-3wuuouxg/preshed_dd0563dec5f54cb4a210a0676d307d73/
      Complete output (224 lines):
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      copying preshed/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      copying preshed/about.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed/tests
      copying preshed/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed/tests
      copying preshed/tests/test_pop.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed/tests
      copying preshed/tests/test_counter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed/tests
      copying preshed/tests/test_hashing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed/tests
      copying preshed/counter.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      copying preshed/maps.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      copying preshed/maps.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      copying preshed/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      copying preshed/counter.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/preshed
      running build_ext
      building 'preshed.maps' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
   








----- BLA BLA BLA TOO MANY ERRORS I REMOVE SOME THINGS OTHERWISE I CANNOT PUBLISH IT BECAUSE IT EXCEEDS THE LIMIT OF CHARACTERS----- 

      





      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6129:52: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                         ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                   ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6129:52: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                          (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                         ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
             PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
             ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6145:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                               ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
            ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6145:26: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                               ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                   ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6145:26: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                               ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
             PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
             ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6145:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:261:7: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) :                    \
            ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6145:59: warning: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:262:14: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
            ((void)PyUnicode_AsUnicode(_PyObject_CAST(op)),\
                   ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:580:1: note: 'PyUnicode_AsUnicode' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3) PyAPI_FUNC(Py_UNICODE *) PyUnicode_AsUnicode(
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      preshed/maps.cpp:6145:59: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**argname) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
                                                                ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:264:8: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_GET_SIZE'
             PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op)))
             ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:451:35: note: expanded from macro 'PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH'
      #define PyUnicode_WSTR_LENGTH(op) _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length((PyObject*)op)
                                        ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:445:1: note: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.3)
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      16 warnings and 6 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-install-o1uwotj4/preshed_3904a612e2894555ad992fe8de7d0ba7/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-install-o1uwotj4/preshed_3904a612e2894555ad992fe8de7d0ba7/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-record-8l6nqsp5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-tdp_0toi/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-tdp_0toi/overlay/include/site/python3.9/preshed Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/5e/8f21b3f32ea3566764d1c90f4360703be7d1739ed7b51cbf89bed00fa331/spacy-2.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=e3dbde5b560fb9dd3706bd6838e66e28119b6aa17bcb0711d53e95c830bcf0a7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/spacy/) (requires-python:>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/bin/python /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-standalone-pip-7uxqp0sn/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/ng/qbwb1qr92vs2p860gzpg858r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-tdp_0toi/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' thinc==7.0.0.dev6 Check the logs for full command output.
Collecting chatterbot
  Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: mathparse<0.2,>=0.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot) (1.2.19)
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo<4.0,>=3.3 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot) (3.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: chatterbot-corpus<1.3,>=1.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk<4.0,>=3.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML<4.0,>=3.12 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from chatterbot-corpus<1.3,>=1.2->chatterbot) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from nltk<4.0,>=3.2->chatterbot) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from nltk<4.0,>=3.2->chatterbot) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from nltk<4.0,>=3.2->chatterbot) (4.61.2)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from nltk<4.0,>=3.2->chatterbot) (2021.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pint>=0.8.1->chatterbot) (21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil<2.8,>=2.7->chatterbot) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from packaging->pint>=0.8.1->chatterbot) (2.4.7)
Installing collected packages: chatterbot
Successfully installed chatterbot-1.0.4
```

I have tried the following other commands

```
pip3 install chatterbot
pip3 install chatterbot==1.0.4
pip3 install chatterbot==1.0.5
pip3 install chatterbot==1.0.2
```

but either they gave me error in the same way, or they told me that the package was missing and after installation it gave me an error in execution

Anyway when I try to run the script it comes back to me

```
[nltk_data] Error loading averaged_perceptron_tagger: <urlopen error
[nltk_data]     [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
[nltk_data]     failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:1129)>
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>
List Trainer: [#######             ] 33%[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 63, in tokenize_sentence
    self.sentence_tokenizer = load_data('tokenizers/punkt/{language}.pickle'.format(
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 750, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 875, in _open
    return find(path_, path + [""]).open()
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 583, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle

  Searched in:
    - '/Users/pietrobon/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/share/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    trainer.train([
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chatterbot/trainers.py", line 103, in train
    statement_search_text = self.chatbot.storage.tagger.get_bigram_pair_string(text)
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 135, in get_bigram_pair_string
    for sentence in self.tokenize_sentence(text.strip()):
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 68, in tokenize_sentence
    self.sentence_tokenizer = load_data('tokenizers/punkt/{language}.pickle'.format(
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 750, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 875, in _open
    return find(path_, path + [""]).open()
  File "/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 583, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle

  Searched in:
    - '/Users/pietrobon/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/share/nltk_data'
    - '/Users/pietrobon/Downloads/JJ/venv/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************


Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix it?
Are there better libraries to start developing an "ai" chatbot in python?

Comment: there was one error in there about missing the `wheel` package -> how about `pip3 install wheel`

Comment: same error with it

Comment: as I know `chatterbot` from `pip` needs Python 3.7. And chatterbot from [GitHub](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot) needs Python 3.8. Error shows line from compiler `GCC` so it may need some C/C++ libraries - sometimes it can be Python source code or at least files `.h` - and you can't install them with `pip` but using other tools. On Linux Ubuntu/Mint/Debian you can install `.h` using `apt install python3.8-dev`

Comment: second error shows `import nltk` `nltk.download('punkt')` which you should run in Python to download dataset `punkt`

Comment: you may have many problems - like missing C/C++ libraries, missing module `wheel`, missing dataset - so resolving one of this problems - like installing `wheel` - can't resolve all problems and you can still see errors but little different.

Comment: How did you install python3.9? brew? pyenv? other? Check those docs to make sure you have all required build dependencies too (ssl, etc.)